# Cross-Site Scripting in visual force input

Tags: visualforce, security, security-review

We have received a security warning regarding Cross-Site Scripting for below input :

```
<apex:inputtext value="{!mergeText}" id="txtField" disabled="true" size="25"/>
```

What changes are required to bypass this warning?
I have tried JSENCODE but these functions are used with javascript/apex:outputText

Comment: do you display this `mergeText` on the page, or is it passed to the back-end?

Comment: It is displayed on the page and also passed to apex class.

Comment: Rohit, is this comment from Checkmarx? If so, can you email rsussland at salesforce dot com the the scan Id of your report?  Thanks.

Comment: @RobertSussland , This comment is from fortify scan.

Comment: Then you should reach out to your Fortify support and notify them of this false positive.